# Sentient truck with living flesh human mouth built into dashboard?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Does anyone remember the title of this (possibly straight to video) movie from the late 1980's / early 1990's?

- Live action.
- English dialogue, but this could have been a dub - the credits indicated that it was made in Hungary.
- The opening theme was a monotonous song - the lyric "to reach the end of the line" was repeated a lot.
- The setting was an authoritarian police state, possibly post apocalyptic.
- The protagonist was the driver of a sentient truck.
- The truck's name was "Monster".
- The truck could speak via a living flesh human mouth built into the dashboard.
- The opening titles may have had a wireframe animation of the truck.
- The protagonist rescues a young girl and agrees to escort her to a sanctuary.
- The protagonist dies towards the end, and his role of driving the truck is taken over by the young girl that he rescued.

Comment: A really solid decription. The only thing that surprises me is that with all this info, you weren't able to google up an answer yourself...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Terminus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminus_(1987_film)) (1987).

> In the year 2037, an international sport has been established, wherein
>   a driver of a truck must cross the country and arrive at a designated
>   terminus, while confronting obstacles and enemies along the way. The
>   lead truck, named "Monster", has been designed by a boy genius
>   (Gabriel Damon) and is to be piloted through the course by a woman
>   named Gus (Karen Allen). Eventually, the truck's AI fails and Gus ends
>   up in uncharted territories. There, she encounters leather-clad
>   "hoods" (hoodlums) that torture her and eventually kill her. Prior to
>   dying, she befriends a fellow prisoner (Johnny Hallyday), who later
>   uses the truck to rescue himself and a young orphan. Meanwhile, the
>   boy genius watches them by an artificial satellite so that he may see
>   how well the truck's software works. The conclusion reveals that as he
>   watches the truck, he is himself watched and evaluated by the sinister
>   doctor (Jürgen Prochnow) who cloned him.

You can see the truck in the clip below, along with the dashboard mouth

For the record, the song you're referencing is "End of the Line" by Stan Ridgway, specially commissioned for the film along with the "Love Story theme".

> *There's no one here who shares my views
>
>   Or sees the way I can see
>
>   But there's just one thing that you'll understand
>
>   You'll have to even up with me
>
>   **At the end of the line (x2)***

Comment: Yes, that's it! It sounds like I've forgotten large chunks of the plot, but the song and the mouth in the dashboard confirm it beyond a doubt.